# How to reverse migration in Laravel using Doctrine DBAL

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, dbal, doctrine-dbal

I'm using PHP 7.3|8.0, Laravel 8.75, Doctrine DBAL 3.6 and MySQL.

I want to change the data type of a column from integer to enum. I also added custom enum type following this guide https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/cookbook/mysql-enums.html.

```
<?php

use App\Types\AccountEnumType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ChangeAccountTypeColumnInAccountTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $connectionParams = [
            'driver' => env('DB_DRIVER'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'dbname' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'user' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        ];
        $connection = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);

        Type::addType('enum', AccountEnumType::class);

        $connection->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');

        Schema::table('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum('account_type', config('enums.account_type'))->default('SAVINGS')->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('account_type')->unsigned()->change();
        });
    }
}
```

The migration file is working fine when migrating but when I rollback I got this exception.

```
   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception 

  Unknown column type "account" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Exception.php:115
    111▕     }
    112▕ 
    113▕     public static function unknownColumnType(string $name): self
    114▕     {
  ➜ 115▕         return new self('Unknown column type "' . $name . '" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has ' .
    116▕             'to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the ' .
    117▕             'known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database ' .
    118▕             'introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use ' .
    119▕             'AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement ' .

      +16 vendor frames 
  17  database/migrations/2023_07_07_091358_change_account_type_column_in_account_table.php:47
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()

      +22 vendor frames 
  40  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I tried using raw SQL statement its working fine

```
 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE accounts MODIFY COLUMN account_type INT");
}
```

But how to do it with schema builder?

Comment: Doctrine DBAL doesn't support enum types, it's causing an exception. If you have to make it work again you have to register type again in down() method.